# Mod_rewrite redirect to specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I will begin by showing you my code and then I will explain what I'm trying to achieve.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^core$ library/core.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I am using core.php as a processor file for several request sent by ajax. When I make the request, it will be something like "http://mysite/core" and I want it to make through the .htaccess file and directly to "http://mysite/library/core.php". I tested it and it runs ok up to that line (I guess it would have been odd not to). However, if the request is not "http://mysite/core", I want to test if that request is neither an existent file, nor a folder, and if it ain't any of those, I want to:

- redirect to "http://mysite/public" if the request is "http://mysite/"
- redirect to "http://mysite/public/blabla" if the request is "http://mysite/blabla"

If I remove the last RewriteRule, everything works fine. However, if I let it be, (even if I access "http://mysite/core") it keeps redirecting me to "http://mysite/public/library/core.php". I can't figure out what's happening. It's like he's not aware of my [L] flag within the first RewriteRule.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^core$ library/core.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` is only applicable for very next `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yes, it works this way. Thank you. Anyway, why is it (in my example) that the [L] hit on the first RewriteRule was not applied ? Whatever came after that ... shouldn't it just be ignored ?

Comment: Actually `L` doesn't stop other rules to execute, it just ends current rule.